# Computer won't boot into BIOS after I had used hairdryer to clean the PSU

Tags: boot, bios, power-supply, hardware-failure

I need help, it is very urgent:

I shut down my computer, unplugged everything, opened the case, saw the power supply unit was dusty and used a hairdryer to clean it; after doing so, my computer won't boot after installing the RAM module and plugging everything in *(won't load the BIOS, screen is black, mouse light is on, keyboard light is off)*

- No change after removing extra RAM, replacing original RAM, or removing all disks 
   [image: My computer:] 
   *Asrock Q1900M with Intel Celeron J1900, using DDR3 RAM (4GB 1600MHz and 8GB 1600MHz DIMMs)*
- I used an electrical copper wire, peeled the insulator layer, and shortcircuited the 3rd and 4th pins from the right on the side with the extruded part, plugged power cable in, and used a voltmeter to measure the voltage between the 2 pins, observed no voltage, and touched them with my hands, feeling nothing

Any ideas?

Comment: Was the power supply connected to the rest of PC when you were cleaning it?

Comment: It was connected.

Comment: When touching a PSU outbound circuit, you shouldn't feel anything as it's low-voltage DC _(dry skin is not a good conductor for low-voltage DC; with wet fingers, you'd likely get a tingle to small shock/burn depending on the max amperage of that circuit)_. Was the hairdryer on cold or hot and did you blow it onto the fan of the PSU _(if the fan spun fast enough, it could have damaged the bearings or motor)_? If the hairdryer was kept at a distance so as not to get the PSU >100C or melt resins, it's unlikely the heat damaged the PCB _(perhaps capacitors, which can be tested with a multimeter)_

Comment: Going to take it to the repairs shop tomorrow, to do some tests. Most likely the Power Supply Unit is dead, CPU can't be dead, don't know if motherboard is dead, though.

Comment: How to best put this, emmm, the air the hairdryer blew out felt... warm? 20 degrees Celsius, or 30 C maybe? I don't know, the air flow was weak, so I thought that was OK...I blew the dust at a very close range...

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς It's highly unlikely the hairdryer created the issue then, as most, if not all, PCB components must be able to withstand 100C, since that's the limit for the CPU before it goes into thermal protection, and sounds more like a coincidence than correlation. _(Please do not create multiple comments if everything can fit into one; please either edit the original or copy/paste both into a new comment, deleting the original)_

Comment: Just replaced my mainboard, PSU and CPU with better ones, after they had been confirmed dead. Going to clean install and redisable half of the system tomorrow, though I now have 12GB RAM, I really don't like those things.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is answered however the answer did not solve my problem, the motherboard and PSU were dead and had been replaced almost a month ago, making the question invalid. It needs to be closed.

Comment: I accepted the answer only because the annoying red notice "Have you considered accepting an answer or start a bounty on this question?" (or similar phrasing), this answer did NOT solve my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hairdryer creating hot air, never use the hairdryer as a dust blower for electronics, unless you need to clean the water droplet from electronic. Ex: cleaning the handphone after getting wet.

And cleaning the PC without proper equipment or grounding can be fatal because our body tends to have ESD (electrostatic discharge) it could make your motherboard / electronic in general to be dead.

Try to take out your power supply.
Test to turn on the power supply outside without anything connected to it (peripherals or motherboard)

How to jump the power supply to turn it on:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPT86.jpg)

If your PSU turn on, check the voltage with multitester/voltmeter, the 12V, 5V, and 3.3V.

Edit:

Below on comment, there is possible your PSU won't turn on because there is no load. So try to connect one of your peripherals like DVD/optic drive or an old HDD or one of your PC fan.

Comment: ATX spec allows PSUs to not turn on without a load. For a proper check one could connect a small 12V bulb to a Molex connector.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, my connector has 24 pins...

Comment: While a static discharge is possible, it has to come from somewhere, so as long as a person wasn't walking in wool socks or doing something that could build up a charge, it's unlikely a static discharge occurred. _(It's good practice to wear a static ground, but the likelihood of a discharge is still extremely low.)_

Comment: @gronostaj i forget about that part :D

Comment: @JW0914 i did barefoot with ceramic tile on the ground, but somehow i got static discharge on my hand and making my HDD dead. So practically we need to take caution about this one.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς check again with a load in my edited answer

Comment: @XCSource I didn't say it can't happen, just that it's extremely unlikely in a non-factory setting, as a static discharge requires cause and effect _(e.g. you need to do something that builds up the charge as the human body does not generate static electricity)_. Much the same as you should touch a car's body before filling with gas to ground yourself before gas flows, touching something metal before handling PCBs would be recommended, but again, there has to be a cause for the static charge buildup for a static discharge to occur _(includes lightning, which creates ambient static charges)_

Comment: @JW0914 - "While a static discharge is possible, it has to come from somewhere" - moving streams of air can build up static, the most familiar example being lightning.

Comment: @JW0914 I did touching the metal door, and the PC case itself before further process. but alas, my HDD broke :) and because we all wear something on our body we can't make static disappear just barely noticeable unless we ground ourselves we can reach almost none but still have it. :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey don't forget the vacuum killer :))

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Have you ever experienced lightning inside a structure on the ground? The only recorded cases of lightning occurring inside of a structure are inside planes at altitude [ball lightning]. This will be my last comment as common sense has left the building - touching metal grounds the human body, discharging any static charge and there are only a handful of clothing materials, such as wool, that can generate a static charge when rubbed against another material, such as carpet.

Comment: You can generate sufficient static charge to spark merely by taking a garment off. What people fail to recognise when they refer to "static" is it is nothing more than a potential difference. The **only** way to remove any potential difference between you & a computer is to touch the computer casing ***whilst it is plugged in & connected to earth***. Adding a heated dry air rotational-brush device to the equation is a really good way of making sure you & the computer are going to be at different potentials. Hair dryers are not earthed, they are double-insulated.